# Merging laravel dingo with laravel-modules and caching config

Tags: laravel, dingo-api

Here is the problem.

I started a dingo project and am using laravel-modules in it. Every module has its own routing files. Using the project in development environment, everything works fine.

But when I run `php artisan config:cache`, when a request comes to laravel, it return the response `The version given was unknown or has no registered routes`. As I see, the problem is dingo just check the default `api.php` and `web.php` files to find the route. But module routes are not stored in that files. I store them in `Modules/module_name/route/api.php` file (as laravel-modules suggested).

Any suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: 0

I have the same probleme, I do the follow code in api.php of module, but i have the fowling error.

RuntimeException : A version is required for an API group definition

I beleave that problem is a required group, but I not have a solution

Answer (score 1):

change api file of module with version param in group session like this:

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');
    
$api->group(['version' => 'v1'], function ($api) {
    ...
});
```